# How to define proptypes here

Tags: reactjs

I can't avoid **Eslint error** ("component is missing in prop type validation").

**How to define proptypes for**:

1. component
2. location

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        cookies.get("token") !== "" && cookies.get("token") !== undefined ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/401",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
PrivateRoute.prototype = {
  component: PropTypes.objectOf(React.Component)
};
Redirect.prototype = {
  location: PropTypes.string
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some misspelling, using `prototype` instead of `propTypes`:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.objectOf(React.Component)
};
```

More propTypes info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)